# Numbered bullets appear distorted in output PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am saving from Word 2013 to PDF using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro. However, numbered bullets appear distorted in the output PDF:

[Word screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1ORJ.jpg) | [Adobe Acrobat/Reader screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHeDA.jpg)

I am guessing it's actually a PDF viewer/renderer issue since the bullets look distorted in Acrobat and Reader, but seem fine in Nitro PDF.

Reader/Acrobat started behaving this way (I think) ever since I turned on Accessibility in Acrobat. I've unchecked everything in Preferences > Accessibility, but the problem remains. (I'm also not sure why Accessibility should have anything to do with this.)

Are there any settings I can tweak to make the numbered bullets display correctly?

Apart from the display issue, sometimes the bullets are indented incorrectly in the PDF. FYI, the same file saved to PDF seamlessly before. I am saving to PDF via the Create PDF command in Word (from the Acrobat menu) or via the Save as Adobe PDF command.

Any suggestions/feedback would be much appreciated.
Edit: tried opening the PDF on a different computer - the numbered bullets still look distorted.

Comment: Have you checked the font used by the lists in the PDF? Does it match the font you used in the original Word document?

Comment: Yes, it uses the same font (Segoe UI). The font is also embedded in the file (an embedded subset actually), and is listed in Properties > Document Properties > Fonts from Acrobat.